# Requesting more Environment directories in one intent

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, storage

I want to request access for more directories:

- Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES
- Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARMS
- Environment.DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS

I am following [scoped directory access guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/scoped-directory-access). I have following code:

```
StorageManager sm = (StorageManager)getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
StorageVolume volume = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume();
Intent intent = volume.createAccessIntent(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES);
startActivityForResult(intent, MY_CODE);
```

This works well for `Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES`, however I need to as for the three mentioned before. As it would not result in good user experience, it is not a good idea to ask for all three subsequently (it would lead to three dialogs). In [Environment documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#DIRECTORY_RINGTONES), android says this:

> This may be combined with DIRECTORY_MUSIC, DIRECTORY_PODCASTS, DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS, and DIRECTORY_ALARMS as a series of directories to categories a particular audio file as more than one type.

Unfortunately, I did not find a way how to request them all in one `intent`. Thank you for your help.